# jQuery animation with a serie of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation

I have the following code which doesn't work, it waits 3 seconds and replaces it automaticly to the final image.

```
        for (var i=1;i<10;i++)
        { 
            setTimeout(function(){$("#laptop").attr("src","img/"+i+".png");},3000);
        }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)** without a for loop

```
var i=1;
var inter=setInterval(function(){
              $("#laptop").attr("src","img/"+i+".png");
              i++;
              if(i==10)
                  clearInterval(inter);   
          },3000);
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/L2Gau/6/)

Comment: Really? Will it not just increase the delay between each image?

Comment: @PranavCBalan FYI, you're forgetting to increase `i` during your `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

You really should just use `setInterval`, since `setTimeout` is non-blocking:

```
var i = 0, end = 10,
int = setInterval(function(){
    $("#laptop").attr("src","img/"+i+".png");
    i++;
    if (i === end) { clearInterval(int) }
}, 3000);
```